# Non-control character in cookie header rejected by undertow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encoding, undertow

We are having Spring Boot v2.7.11 application with undertow web server.

I am having troubles understanding how cookie header is "treated" differently from other headers.

So, if I make curl request with following header: `--header 'Cookie: foo=ä'` I am getting following exception:

```
j.l.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [195] was present in the cookie value or attribute
at i.u.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:149)
at io.undertow.util.Cookies.parseCookie(Cookies.java:302)
at io.undertow.util.Cookies.parseRequestCookies(Cookies.java:244)
at io.undertow.util.Cookies.parseRequestCookies(Cookies.java:222)
at io.undertow.util.Cookies.parseRequestCookies(Cookies.java:213)
at i.u.server.HttpServerExchange.requestCookies(HttpServerExchange.java:1200)
at i.u.server.HttpServerExchange.getRequestCookie(HttpServerExchange.java:1181)
...
```

On the other hand if I pass any other header, i.e. : `--header 'foo: ä'`, no exception however.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you are using Keycloak, [bug report KEYCLOAK-17784](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7930) may be relevant, with my emphasis added: _"International users using non-ascii symbols such as the german äöü
will make Keycloak set the KEYCLOAK_REMEMBER_ME cookie without URL
encoding. This will trigger an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
UT000173 exception in **undertow's cookie parser which does not
allow non-ascii characters**."_